# Get only files committed info in svn log -verbose

Tags: svn, unix, sed, awk, cut

How to get only the files committed as the output from svn -verbose

```
  svn log -v  . -r 101
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  r101 | username | 2013-05-10 16:27:55 -0400 (Fri, 10 May 2013) | 1 line
  Changed paths:
     M /branches/1.0/ssac/codes/filename1.java
     M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename2.java
     M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename3.java
     M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filenmae4.java
     M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename5.java
     M /branches/1.0/vclpcc/filename6.java
Ticket-1
```

I tired this:

```
  svn log -v  . -r 101 | awk '/Changed paths/{ P=1; next } /Ticket-1/ {exit} P'
```

Output:

```
 M /branches/1.0/ssac/codes/filename1.java
 M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename2.java
 M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename3.java
 M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filenmae4.java
 M /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename5.java
 M /branches/1.0/vclpcc/filename6.java
```

Is there a better way ? and also truncate "M" meta data ?

Intended output:

```
 /branches/1.0/ssac/codes/filename1.java
 /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename2.java
 /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename3.java
 /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filenmae4.java
 /branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename5.java
 /branches/1.0/vclpcc/filename6.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ svn log -v . -r 101 | awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'
/branches/1.0/ssac/codes/filename1.java
/branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename2.java
/branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename3.java
/branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filenmae4.java
/branches/1.0/ssac/extn/filename5.java
/branches/1.0/vclpcc/filename6.java
```

Comment: Yeah that also. Its breaking on output which has spaces/tabs. Any better to achieve only committed files ? Also in this case I'm giving the Ticket-1 string - pattern. But if the developer misses the Ticket-1 in svn comments, this might not work at all :(

Comment: Your suggestion worked. But is there a way to get the files committed without giving the patterns in the awk - like "changed paths" and "Ticket-1"

Comment: It's not always "M" ..could be "A" "M" or "D"

Comment: So then `awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'`

Answer (score -2):

```
svn log -v | grep '^[ADMR]' | gawk {print $2}
```

If I have forgotten some statuses, they can be added to grep-string

Comment: You never need `grep` with `awk`. Your `awk` script needs be quoted as currently the shell will interpret `$2` as a shell variable. Also this will fail for cases where folders/filenames have spaces in.

Comment: @sudo_O - yes, it was lazy attempt, from memory - I can eliminate grep for the cost of more complex awk's code - but I wrote *idea*. Space-problem was forgotten also

Comment: There is no extra *cost* by *(in complexity or resources)* just using `awk` in fact it's completely the opposite. You are parsing the input twice instead of once with `awk`. This also will produce false positives because you only anchored the left side of the regexp match.